# How to Replay an Audio-Blob in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I want to replay an audio blob (wav), recorded in javascript using the Web Audio API.

I tried the following:

```
function replayBlob( blob ) {
    var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var audio0 = new Audio(blobURL);
    audio0.play();
}
```

But this code does not replay the audio blob.

I also tried replaying the blob via an html audio tag:

```
<audio id="wavSource" 
    src="blob:http%3A//localhost/f0b6bae9-7c70-4793-8436-7755a40bae3f" 
    type="audio/wav" controls>
</audio>
```

with the blob source being set programmatically using:

```
var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
document.getElementById("wavSource").src = blobURL;
```

and the audio play call using:

```
document.getElementById("wavSource").play();
```

but no sound is played.

For verification, I downloaded the blob with:

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.style = "display: none";
a.href = blobURL;
a.download = "test.wav";
a.click();
```

The downloaded blob contains the correct audio data in the wav format. **How can I play this audio data from the blob in javascript?**

Comment: are you sure the blob is in wav format? that means if you download the blob, it will play in a media player...

Comment: yes it plays in a media player. any other ideas why i might not hear anything?

Comment: try adding controls and appending it to the body and seeing if you can play it that way

Comment: I tried but also no sound is played, please find my update in the post. Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: you can't hard-code a blob url into the source, it has to be set with javascript.

Comment: the code above was just an example, the blob is actually set programmatically. see my post below. any ideas why it is still silent?

Comment: I encountered a similar issue. It turned out that my blobUrl was initially null. It has crashed the player, so even if it was set to a correct value later, the player would not respond.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using Web Audio to record, I figure you can use it for playback as well, right? If so, recorder.js has a how-to in the README: https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs

I'll go ahead and copy the gist of here, in case recorder.js changes in the future. You have two Float32Arrays (left and right channel) and then do this;

```
function getBufferCallback( buffers ) {
    var newSource = audioContext.createBufferSource();
    var newBuffer = audioContext.createBuffer( 2, buffers[0].length, audioContext.sampleRate );
    newBuffer.getChannelData(0).set(buffers[0]);
    newBuffer.getChannelData(1).set(buffers[1]);
    newSource.buffer = newBuffer;

    newSource.connect( audioContext.destination );
    newSource.start(0);
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain how it can apply in above context ? (with recoder.js)

Answer (score 6):

The simplest option is to convert to a 64 bit encoding

```
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e) {
    const srcUrl = e.target.result;
    audioNode.src = srcUrl;
};
reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
```