# How to convert Blob url in Expo React -native into mp3 format and playback it?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, blob, mp3

I'm trying create a audio recorder and playback button ,i was successful in creating recording and stop it ,but the file is saved as the blob ,how to convert it into mp3 and playback.
`

```
import {View,Image,Text,Button,StyleSheet,TextInput,TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import {Stack,useRouter} from 'expo-router';
import { Audio } from 'expo-av';
import logo from  '../assets/images/swecha.png';
import mic from  '../assets/icons/mic.png';
import playback from '../assets/icons/playback.png'
import stop from '../assets/icons/stop.png'
import * as React from 'react';

const Home =() => {
  
  const onpressImage=() =>{
    console.log('Mic Clicked')
  }
  const [recording, setRecording] = React.useState();

  async function startRecording() {
    try {
      console.log('Requesting permissions..');
      await Audio.requestPermissionsAsync();
      await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
        allowsRecordingIOS: true,
        playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
      });

      console.log('Starting recording..');
      const { recording } = await Audio.Recording.createAsync( Audio.RecordingOptionsPresets.HIGH_QUALITY
      );
      setRecording(recording);
      console.log('Recording started');
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Failed to start recording', err);
    }
  }

  async function stopRecording() {
    console.log('Stopping recording..');
    setRecording(undefined);
    await recording.stopAndUnloadAsync();
    await Audio.setAudioModeAsync(
      {
        allowsRecordingIOS: false,
      }
    );
    const uri = recording.getURI();
    console.log('Recording stopped and stored at', uri);
    
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.view1}>
        <Image source={logo}/>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.view2}>
        <TextInput placeholder='Enter your text' style={styles.input}></TextInput>
        
      </View>

      <View style={styles.view3}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={startRecording}>
        <Image style={styles.mic} source={mic}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={stopRecording}>
        <Image style={styles.mic} source={stop}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={onpressImage}>
        <Image style={styles.mic} source={playback}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  view1: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    alignItems:'center'
  },
  view3: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    flexDirection:'row',
    verticalAlign:'top',
    display:'flex',
    marginRight:100,
    justifyContent:'center'
    
  },
  view2: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    alignContent:'center',
    alignItems:'center',
    

  },
  input:{
    width:'80%',
    height:100,
    borderWidth:1,
    margin:20

  },
  mic:{
    width:40,
    height:40,
    margin:40
    
  },
  
}
);
export default Home;
```

`
the output after stopping the recording is....
[it just giving the blob url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/873n6.png)

i just want the code to convert the blob into the mp3 and playback it.

Comment: [Does this help in any way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34934862/how-to-replay-an-audio-blob-in-javascript)